# .NET COM Visible DLL vs. Active X DLL

Tags: c#, com, vb6, activex

I have a situation where a third party application loads a collection of VB6 Active X DLL extensions. The only constraint for these extensions is that they contain a set of predefined IDispatch functions.

Would it be possible to implement a COM visible .NET DLL that could be used interchangeably in place of the Active X DLL, or is there a fundamental difference between Active X DLLs and .NET visible COM DLLs that would prevent this?

Comment: Yes, there's only one kind of IDispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to build complete ActiveX objects in .NET. It's possible (although not terribly likely) that the application is going to QI for something other than IDispatch, but your best bet is to just try it. Keep in mind that using .NET for this type of thing has performance implications and side-by-side framework versioning implications.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric. Could you please explain what you mean about "QI for something other than IDispatch"? What I have at the moment is a standard .NET object marked as COM visible which I have been successfully able to create and use via Powershell. If the application is querying for IDispatch, should it find this? The reason I ask is that this is not being picked up as an extension in its current form.